# List of branches of a Python tree

Tags: python, tree

I have a tree of Python objects. The tree is defined intrinsically: each object has a list (potentially empty) of children.
I would like to be able to print a list of all paths from the root to each leaf.

[image]

In the case of the tree above, this would mean:

```
result = [
          [Node_0001,Node_0002,Node_0004],
          [Node_0001,Node_0002,Node_0005,Node_0007],
          [Node_0001,Node_0003,Node_0006],
         ]
```

The nodes must be treated as objects and not as integers (only their integer ID is displayed).
I don't care about the order of branches in the result. Each node has an arbitrary number of children, and the level of recursion is not fixed either.

I am trying a recursive approach:

```
def get_all_paths(node):
    if len(node.children)==0:
        return [[node]]
    else:
        return [[node] + get_all_paths(child) for child in node.children]
```

but I end-up with nested lists, which is not what I want:

```
[[Node_0001,
  [Node_0002, [Node_0004]],
  [Node_0002, [Node_0005, [Node_0007]]]],
 [Node_0001, [Node_0003, [Node_0006]]]]
```

**Any help would be gladly welcomed, this problem is driving me crazy :p**

Thanks

Comment: Consider using inorder traversal. Left-Root-Right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying:

```
def get_all_paths(node):
    if len(node.children) == 0:
        return [[node]]
    return [
        [node] + path for child in node.children for path in get_all_paths(child)
    ]
```

For each child of a node, you should take all paths of the child and prepend the node itself to each path. You prepended the node to the list of paths, not every path individually.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks  :D
I get:
`[[Node_0001, Node_0002, Node_0004],
 [Node_0001, Node_0002, Node_0005, Node_0007],
 [Node_0001, Node_0003, Node_0006]]`

Comment: I like this approach of first finding all the branch combinations, then doing operations on those branches (e.g. find the total length of the branch). Most other solutions I see for tree walking seem to perform operations during the tree walking and the code becomes pretty messy.